# why do Vagrant docs suggest using public IP address 33.33.33.10 for local VMs?

Tags: routing, vagrant, private-ip

I'm following a [tutorial](http://vimeo.com/21312930) to set up [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) (a tool to build and configure portable virtual machine images), and it seems that [vagrant documentation suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=vagrant%2033.33.33.10) using IPv4 address **33.33.33.10** to configure a new box.

That is a [publicly routed IP adress](http://whois.domaintools.com/33.33.33.10), so I'm a bit confused why using this address is suggested. Since I don't own this network, I should not use an address from the **33.33.33.10/8** range. Am I correct in thinking that I should only use either a public address from a network I own, or an address from one of the private ranges as defined in [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)? If so, why does Vagrant documentation suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The vagrant documentation does not appear to suggest to use 33.33.33.10.](https://www.google.com/search?q=33.33.33.10%20site:vagrantup.com)

Digging deeper into the official documentation, I was only able to find RFC 1918 addresses in use.

Given the apparent close association between Vagrant and this incorrectly-used address, I can only surmise that the docs *did* refer to it in the past, and were later corrected.

Oh, and you definitely should not use someone else's public IP address, even on your own private network. Very Bad Things can (and probably will) happen.

Answer (score 4):

As to why they've suggested you do it I'm going to go with "they're idiots". But really that's something we can't answer here. Why do people say or do anything? You'd need to ask the person who wrote that documentation.

As to what you should do, you're absolutely right: You shouldn't be using public IP addresses you don't own.